# JEST- some of the tests are not running when I run "npm run jest" in async methods

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, testing, redis, jestjs

I am testing a service that saves data in REDIS, in my describe I have several "it" tests , the "it" tests are testing a variable that is given a value by an async function, I noticed that when I run the tests the "describe" cant see the test suites ("it") inside of it.
I'm getting an error like this: " Your test suite must contain at least one test".
I noticed when I'm removing the line of the variable that gets data from an async function it does see the tests but they are not relevant because they test the value of the variable that gets his data from the async function, I leaving the piece of code to help you understand better what I'm talking about.

```
describe("some testing", ()=>{
describe("redisProcessor", ()=>{
    console.log("---------------------------debug2")
    aisListenerSpec.run("123456")
    aisListenerSpec.redisProcessor(JSON.stringify(validMessage));

    let isOkay = true
    aisListenerSpec.redisSetter.client.hgetall("________someString______",(err, result)=>{
        console.log("---------------------------debug3")
        for (const key in result) {
            if(validMessage[key]!==undefined)
                if(JSON.stringify(validMessage[key])!==result[key]) isOkay = false;
        }

        console.log("---------------------------debug4")

        it("________someString______${missionId} should be 2 another fields: messageTime and missionId", ()=>{
            expect(result["messageTime"]).toBeTruthy();
            expect(result["missionId"]).toBe("123456");
        })
        it("________someString______${missionId} should be the same the validMessage",  ()=>{
            console.log("---------------------------debug5")
            expect(isOkay).toBeTruthy();
        })
        console.log("---------------------------debug6")
    })
})
```

here is the cli outputs

[here is the cli outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdoBD.png)

It seems like that jest finished before getting to the tests.

**thank ahead!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous code is hard to think about. A common gotcha is not realizing that the moment you call anything asynchronous, the function you are in immediately goes to the next line of code. Then, at some future and indeterminate time, the callback is invoked. Maybe.

This is what's happening in you code when you call `aisListenerSpec.redisSetter.client.hgetall`. All of the calls to `it` are inside of the callback and aren't called in the `describe`. They are called sometime later, after the `describe` has already returned.

Also, a lot of you setup code should probably be in a call to `beforeEach` and not inside of the `describe`. This gives you better control over when the setup code in invoke and by running it for each test, helps reduce side effects in your test suite.

Jest has a [fairly complete page](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) describing how to test code like this. I've synthesized a couple of quick examples that should help if you just want a quick solution.  But I do recommend you go and read the link and familiarize yourself with the ways to handle this in Jest.

Option one. Use `done`. The set up will not return until `done` is called. If `done` is never called, you'll get a timeout error and the test will fail:

```js
describe("test async thing", () => {

  let results

  beforeEach(done => {
    processWithCallback("foo", (err, result) => {
      if (err) { 
        done(err)
      } else {
        results = result
        done()
      }
    }
  }

  it("did a thing", () => {
    expect(result.foo).toBe('foo')
  })
})
```

Option two. Use and return a `Promise`. If the `Promise` never resolves, you will get a timeout error:

```js
describe("test async thing", () => {

  let results

  beforeEach(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      processWithCallback("foo", (err, result) => {
        if (err) { 
          reject(err)
        } else {
          results = result
          resolve()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  it("did a thing", () => {
    expect(result.foo).toBe('foo')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the first option and it worked for me.